# How to convert column values into a single array in scala?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, spark-structured-streaming

I am trying to convert all columns of my dataframe into single arrays.
Is there an operation supported in structured streaming by which we can perform something opposite to "explode"?
Any suggestion is much appreciated !!!

Tried collect() and collectAsList() . But it is not supported in streaming

```
+---+---------------+----------------+--------+
|row|ADDRESS_TYPE_CD|DISCONTINUE_DATE|param_cd|
+---+---------------+----------------+--------+
|0  |1              |null            |7       |
|2  |6              |null            |1       |
+---+---------------+----------------+--------+
```

My result should look like :

```
+---+---------------+----------------+--------+
|row|ADDRESS_TYPE_CD|DISCONTINUE_DATE|param_cd|
+---+---------------+----------------+--------+
[0,2]  [1,6]          [null,null]     [7,2]
+---+---------------+----------------+--------+
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `collect_list` on all your columns for instance. It would go as follows:

```scala
val aggs = df.columns.map(c => collect_list(col(c)) as c)
df.select(aggs :_*).show()
+------+---------------+----------------+--------+
|   row|ADDRESS_TYPE_CD|DISCONTINUE_DATE|param_cd|
+------+---------------+----------------+--------+
|[0, 2]|         [1, 6]|    [null, null]|  [7, 1]|
+------+---------------+----------------+--------+
```

Comment: Unfortunately this does not work in Structured Streaming.

Comment: I had not realized that your question was about streams. Can you be more specific about what you are trying to do? Aggregating an entire stream is not really possible. Streams do not really end... Do you have a time column?

Comment: No , I don't have a time column.The above dataframe is a subpart of a code where I am interested to find the corresponding "row" column of the minimum "param_cd" .Since min () and max () functions are also not supported , I was trying to convert them into arrays and then perform array operations onto them.

Comment: min and max are available within windows. That might be what you need but that's hard to say without more details about your code